# Tab key press with external blue tooth keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I'm handling tab key ('\t') by calling  delegate "shouldChangeCharactersInRange". It works fine from the simulator using Hardware Keyboard, but it does not work with device using external blue tooth keyboard, even the delegate "shouldChangeCharactersInRange" is not fired. Do I need to handle differently for external blue tooth keyboard?